# How to prefer JARs from Weblogic domain over those from weblogic system

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, weblogic, classloader, weblogic12c

I am using *Weblogic Server 12.1.1* and copied some JARs to my domain's `lib` folder. One of the JARs is a `org.apache.commons.io` jar. Now I have the problem that Weblogic itself comes with a different version of *commons-io* in its system classpath and so I get *NoSuchMethodErrors*. Is there any way to configure Weblogic to prefer the libs from domain over those from Weblogic system?

The Filtering Classloader works only on those JARs provided with the application (`WEB-INF/lib`).

Comment: Instead of adding it to the domain lib folder, have you tried editing `setDomainEnv.sh` or `startWebLogic.sh` and putting the new jar on the classpath? Have you tried going to the `Server Start` tab in the admin console and changing the classpath there?

Comment: I dont think Weblogic allows this. the idea is if you need a library over whats system - then you'll have to bundle it within your web app or EAR and then use the solution @Blekit has

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to put JARs into the domain /lib, I think you have to edit the setDomainEnv.cmd and modify PRE_CLASSPATH variable.

Example:
set PRE_CLASSPATH=C:\myinstallation\Middleware\wlserver_12.1\domains\mydomain\lib\myjar.jar

But, if is possible to put JARs in WEB-INF/lib or APP-INF/lib, then use @Blekit solution, it's cleaner.

Comment: I now managed to move my code into WEB-INF/lib and so I could use the 'prefer-webinf-classes' property.

Answer (score 7):

Use one of follwing options in `weblogic.xml` descriptor:

- `prefer-application-packages`
- `prefer-web-inf-classes`

Details are described [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E24329_01/web.1211/e21049/weblogic_xml.htm).

Comment: This does only work with JARs provided within the applicaton ('WEB-INF/lib' or 'APP-INF/lib') but not with JARs provided in the domain lib folder.

Comment: According to [this](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E24329_01/web.1211/e24368/classloading.htm#i1097083) article, "domain /lib classloader will be the parent of any Java EE application", so it should work out of the box. Maybe try using the Java EE libraries feature?

Comment: Yes, "domain/lib" is a parent of the EE application class loader, but the article also says that it is a child of the overall system class loader. And that is my problem. I would need some kind of "prefer" config for the "domain/lib" classes.

Answer (score 2):

For completeness, i must say that putting commons-io into the domain/lib folder is a bad solution. The problem you describe is a good reason not to put widely used libraries into this folder. The problem might be circumvented by an even worse idea: moving that library higher up in the classloader hierarchy. If you insist on excluding commons-io from your application deliverables, you might install commons-io as an endorsed lib in the jdk. (see [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/standards/)) This would nail down your version of commons-io for every application including weblogic itself. Of course, this would be a problem if you need to contact weblogic support.