# com.jayway.jsonpath and Weblogic 12c

Tags: dependencies, weblogic, conflict

In my Spring-Boot project I use this dependency:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.jayway.jsonpath</groupId>
  <artifactId>json-path</artifactId>
  <version>2.0.0</version>
</dependency>
```

This dependency uses internally the dependency json-smart 2.3. When I try to deploy my project in Weblogic 12C I get following error:

```
java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: defaultReader
at com.jayway.jsonpath.spi.json.JsonSmartJsonProvider.<init> (JsonSmartJsonProvider.java:39)
at com.jayway.jsonpath.internal.DefaultsImpl.jsonProvider(DefaultsImpl.java:21)
at com.jayway.jsonpath.Configuration.defaultConfiguration(Configuration.java:174)
at com.jayway.jsonpath.internal.JsonContext.<init>(JsonContext.java:52)
at com.jayway.jsonpath.JsonPath.parse(JsonPath.java:596)
```

I have already tried the solutions proposed in:

[JSON Parser -java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: defaultReader](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40954331/json-parser-java-lang-nosuchfielderror-defaultreader)

Specifically, I have tried to add in my weblogic.xml file the net.minidev.json.*
dependency preference and to give priority to my war classes with: prefer-web-inf-classes with no success. My Weblogic server has an old version of smart-json (version 1.3) and it always gains preference when deploying my project. I cannot update the servers smart-json jar dependency since I don't have permissions to perform the change. I have also tried to use Weblogic's external dependency folder with no luck ([How to prefer JARs from Weblogic domain over those from weblogic system](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23128846/how-to-prefer-jars-from-weblogic-domain-over-those-from-weblogic-system)).

Is there any way to make com.jayway.jsonpath dependency work with Weblogic?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try using prefer-application-packages instead in your weblogic.xml i.e.

```
<prefer-application-packages>
      <package-name>com.jayway.*</package-name>
</prefer-application-packages>
```

In order for this to work make sure that prefer-web-inf-classes is false (that is the default)